# why is firefox 7.0.1 displays result too slow in asp.net webforms app?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, firebug, internet-explorer-9

In my asp.net webforms application I use firebug to look how much time a request takes. With some pages the request is finished according to firebug but Firefox does not display until a long time after? when I use IE 9 for example it displays the page much quicker? It looks like this is a specific firefox issue. How can I speed up the display?

Comment: Can you post a link to the site? Without that, there isn't too much we can do. Or, even better: If you suspect that a certain component is slowing it, you could post the code for it.

Comment: Try https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/ as a Firefox plugin.  Great add-on for performance testing.  It will grade your site and provide suggestions to areas where performance is slow (e.g. images, css, js).  Also ready Scott Hanselman's blog for additional tips: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx.